# How to update the time of each row and check if its updated or not

Tags: sql-server, mysql, query, execution-plan

| Name | Time | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| T1 | 9/12/2020 12:12:09 | expected |
| T2 | 8/06/2020 11:09:12 | expected |

These are table name and updated time in the DB I want to get the status and time of updation of specific tables .Set the status as "expected" for tables where updation happening daily and "not expected" when when updation miss out daily

Comment: Shown data does not allow to solve your task. You must have the info about all updates - then you may check if a gap of over a day in updating exists. Or, during updating, you may compare new and old values for a range between them in a trigger.

Comment: Is this question for **Microsoft SQL Server** (which is what the `sql-server` tag means) or **MySQL** or both?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need in

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tr_bu_check_gap
BEFORE UPDATE
ON {tablename}
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.Status = CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(NEW.Time, OLD.Time) > 1
                      THEN 'not expected'
                      ELSE 'expected'
                      END;
```

?

PS. This is solution for MySQL only. For SQL Server it can be similar, but syntax adaptation needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to check if a table was updated on a daily basis, then you probably can use this query. You need to alter it a bit to give you the required results. Such as a CASE statement like Akina is referring to. And don't forget to change the database name in the WHERE clause or remove that completely.

```
  SELECT T1.database_id, T1.object_id, T1.last_user_update, T3.type, T3.type_desc, T2.name
  FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats T1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.objects T2 ON T1.object_id = T2.object_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.indexes T3 ON T1.object_id = T3.object_id
  WHERE T3.type in (0,1)--heaps and clustered indexes
  AND T1.database_id = DB_ID('StackOverFlow2010')
```